# What is the difference between github enterprise 'cloud' and 'On premise'

Tags: github-enterprise

We are investigating how to integrate our app with Github Enterprise.
There are 2 different deployment models - 'Cloud' and 'On Premise'

I have been looking around but couldn't find the differences between the two.
Maybe there is no such difference

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The basic difference is that GitHub Enterprise Server is software you deploy on a virtual machine you provision and control (on-premise here is a bit of a misnomer since your VM could be in AWS).
GitHub Enterprise Cloud, on the other hand, is an enterprise-level of service at GitHub.com.

You'll find more [here](https://help.github.com/en/github/getting-started-with-github/githubs-products).